# Current Physical Applications of Elastic Fractals

Tags: material-science, elasticity, fractals

Are there any known uses of modeling with elastic fractals in current physical applications? (Especially uses concerning with self-similarity)

Answer (score 1):

The elastic properties of Aerogels are widely studied, and these are fractal over a certain length-scale.